# How to apply function to every row in a pandas dataframe that requires multiple rows in the calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, function, multirow

Just an example...
I have a 5M row dataframe full of runners and a log of how many miles they ran on any given day. If a runner doesn't run on a day, there is no 0 entry.

| Runner | Day | Miles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| A | 8 | 4 |
| A | 9 | 2 |

I'm trying to get a field for how much they ran in the last 7 calendar days (not including the current row), as well as the next 7 calendar days (including current row).

| Runner | Day | Miles | Last 7 | Next 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | null | 7 |
| A | 3 | 4 | 3 | 10 |
| A | 8 | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| A | 9 | 2 | 10 | 2 |

I think can get the answer for a single row.

Next 7 for row 1 for example...

df.loc[(df['Runner'] == 'A') & (df['day'] >= 1) & (df['day'] < 1+7)]['Miles'].sum()

I'm just unsure how to apply this type of thing to every row in an efficient way. The methods I've seen so far only utilize data from the same row. Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you may use rolling sum.

Let's say the maximum day number is 20

```
max_day = 20
```

And these are the lists of all runners and all days

```
import numpy as np
runners = df['Runner'].unique()
days = np.arange(1, max_day)
```

Then we can get a complete list of runner and day combinations

```
all_combos = [(r, d) for r in runners for d in days]
```

In the 1st line of the following 4-line code, we fill the zeros back, then in the 2nd we group the data by runner and in the 3rd we apply rolling sum on `Miles` requiring at least only 1 record to do a `sum`. You may adjust this parameter. The last line takes care of the format.

```
rollingsum = df.set_index(['Runner', 'Day']).reindex(all_combos).fillna(0)\
    .groupby('Runner')\
    ['Miles'].rolling(7, min_periods=1).sum()\
    .droplevel(1).rename('rs').reset_index()
```

We only need to do 7-day sum once, and shift the records for 'last-7-day' and 'next-7-day' by assigning two new, shifted `Day` columns to replace the original one, and merge the results.

```
df.merge(
    rollingsum.assign(Day = rollingsum['Day']+1).rename(columns={'rs': 'last_7_days'}),
    on = ['Runner', 'Day'],
    how = 'left'
).merge(
    rollingsum.assign(Day = rollingsum['Day']-6).rename(columns={'rs': 'next_7_days'}),
    on = ['Runner', 'Day'],
    how = 'left'
)

  Runner  Day  Miles  last_7_days  next_7_days
0      A    1      3          NaN          7.0
1      A    3      4          3.0         10.0
2      A    8      4          7.0          6.0
3      A    9      2          8.0          2.0
```